# AutoLayout for a presented ViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uiviewanimationtransition

I have implemented a custom viewController transition whereby I present a new ViewController as a pop-over. This resembles something like an alertViewController.  I have written the transition handler and set my presenting viewController as the delegate and than preset this presented view controller like this:

```
 @IBAction func pickOption(sender: UIButton) {

      let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

      let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OptionVC")

      vc.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext

      vc.transitioningDelegate = self

      self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)      

   }
```

Here is where I am confused about proceeding with the layout.  I wish to have this presented ViewController take up a small fraction of the frame of the presenting ViewController's View,  preferably using Autolayout to set margin constraints.  However, both the ViewController's in this are separate scenes in Interface Builder.

In the transition handler, the canonical thing to do seems to be adding the presented ViewController's view to a "context" view and handle animations there.  Then call `transitionContext.completeTransition()`.   Now that the presented ViewController's view is a subview of the presenting ViewController's view, I would like the autolayout constraints to be present but as I previously stated this isn't obvious how to do given both views are in separate scenes in IB.

Thanks in advance for any advice for guidance.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm trying to do a similar thing.

Comment: i forget what became of this issue but looking at it now it doesn't seem like a good idea to set the constraints in IB in this case since they are in different Storyboards.  this would be weird even if they were in different Xibs.  they simply aren't in the same view hierarchy at "build time".  i would guess setting the constraints in the animator after adding the "toView" to the "containerView" should work here.